# Initialising a CoffeeScript class instance from a hash

Tags: oop, coffeescript

I thought this might be built-in, but doesn't seem to be. What's the best way to do populate a new class instance from a hash of properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed built in. You can put @ symbols infront of the variables inside the hash:

```
class Cat
  constructor: ({@name, @age}) ->


myCat = new Cat {name:'kitty', age:3}
```

This is part of "Destructuring Assignment" which you can read about on [the coffescript website](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/). It even works with nested objects, arrays and even splats.

Comment: Thanks, had no idea this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
class Foo
  constructor: (params = {}) ->
    for key, value of params
      this[key] = value

f = new Foo(var1: "foo", var2: "bar")
console.log(f)
```

Comment: I'd recommend `for own ...` here, it almost never matters but it will drive you nuts when it does.